# Hover preview with CSS instead of JS

Tags: html, css, preview

is there a way to make something like [this](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/)

Using only css and html? And if it is possible please give me an example :)

THX.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look: [CSS Popup Image Viewer](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-popup-image-viewer/).

```css
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 50;
}

.thumbnail span {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 5px;
  left: -1000px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span {
  /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0;
  left: 60px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
}
```

```html
<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" width="100px" height="66px" border="0" /><span><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" /><br />Simply beautiful.</span></a>

<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" width="100px" height="66px" border="0" /><span><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" /><br />So real, it's unreal. Or is it?</span></a>

<br />
<br />

<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">Dynamic Drive<span><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" /><br />Dynamic Drive</span></a><br />
<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">Zoka Coffee<span><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" /><br />Zoka Coffee</span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, how do you think is it possible to prevent the screen leaving of preview when the thumbnail is close to the edge of screen?

Comment: Did you can explain a little better?

Comment: best answer ..save my more time